# Rich filtering capabilities with MUnit in Scala

Tags: scala, munit

MUnit is a new Scala testing library with [rich filtering capabilities](https://scalameta.org/munit/blog/2020/02/01/hello-world.html#rich-filtering-capabilities).

Here's the example on the website that I cannot get working:

```
import scala.util.Properties
import munit._
object Windows213 extends Tag("Windows213")
class MySuite extends FunSuite {
  // reminder: type Test = GenericTest[Any]
  override def munitNewTest(test: Test): Test = {
    val isIgnored =
      options.tags(Windows213) && !(
        Properties.isWin &&
        Properties.versionNumberString.startsWith("2.13")
      )
    if (isIgnored) test.withBody(() => Ignore)
    else test
  }

  test("windows-213".tag(Windows213)) {
    // Only runs when operating system is Windows and Scala version is 2.13
  }
  test("normal test") {
    // Always runs like a normal test.
  }
}
```

Changing from `options.tags` to `test.tags` solves one of the errors.

The `if (isIgnored) test.withBody(() => Ignore)` line is still  erroring out with this message:

```
[error] /Users/powers/Documents/code/my_apps/munit-example/src/test/scala/com/github/mrpowers/munit/example/RichFiltersSpec.scala:16:40: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : munit.Tag
[error]  required: MySuite.this.TestValue
[error]     (which expands to)  scala.concurrent.Future[Any]
[error]     if (isIgnored) test.withBody(() => Ignore)
[error]                                        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Test / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

**Update**

The feature [is currently broken](https://github.com/scalameta/munit/issues/62) but [is scheduled to be fixed](https://github.com/scalameta/munit/pull/63).

Will report back with an update when the example is fixed.

Comment: From looking through the source on github, it looks like this wants to be `if (isIgnored) test.withTags(Set(Ignore))`

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed as of version 0.6.0-M1.

[This is the new syntax](https://github.com/scalameta/munit/issues/62#issuecomment-597514491).

This code works as expected:

```
package com.github.mrpowers.munit.example

import scala.util.Properties
import munit._

object Windows213 extends Tag("Windows213")

class MySuite extends FunSuite {

  override def munitTestTransforms = super.munitTestTransforms ++ List(
    new TestTransform("Windows213", { test =>
      val isIgnored =
        test.tags(Windows213) && !(
          Properties.isWin &&
            Properties.versionNumberString.startsWith("2.13")
          )
      if (isIgnored) test.tag(Ignore)
      else test
    })
  )

  test("windows-213".tag(Windows213)) {
    assertEquals(2, 3)
  }

  test("normal test") {
    assertEquals(2, 2)
  }

}
```